# Installing EFI boot on 128GB memory card

Tags: windows, performance, efi, memory-card

I am using laptop having 5200rpm hdd, and I stuck with its speed, so I was thinking to purchase a ssd which can improve performance but hdd are so expensive, and I can't keep both hdd in my laptop. So one thought came in my mind to install Windows on memory which can easily fit into memory card slot. But there are various questions,

Will it improve performance?

About age of memory card?

Does flash storage supports EFI?

Any other alternative to improve performance other than replacing this HDD with SSD or SSHD.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won’t improve performance, because SD cards and the like are optimized for linear read/write performance. That’s what you need when taking photos or recording videos, after all. Also, they wear out *much* faster than full-fledged SSDs. Reading data is no problem, of course, but Windows doesn’t just read but also write. A lot.

Depending on how your card reader is connected internally, you might indeed be able to boot from it. You can try this with an inexpensive small card, just put some Linux distribution on it.

It won’t work with Windows anyway because it refuses to be installed to removable disks of any kind.

If you keep your laptop running for extended periods of time, more RAM may improve performance tremendously, with increased cache size and all.

Comment: I am using which has 16GB RAM but while reading files from HDD, there is a small lag issue. Is there any solution to improve performance?

Comment: What do you mean by “lag”?